# Equally spaced vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: geometry, 3d

In $\mathbb{R}^2$ it is trivial to find a set of $N$ unit vectors that is equally spaced.  But in $\mathbb{R}^3$ finding a set of $N$ vectors that are equally spaced is not that easy.  How would you go about finding such a set, for a given $N$?

What I know is that using the vertices of the five platonic solids we can make $4$ (tetrahedron), $6$ (octahedron), $8$ (cube), $12$ (icosahedron), and $20$ (dodecahedron), vectors to be equally spaced.  Is there any other $N$ for which we can place the vectors in $3D$ space such that they are equally spaced?

Comment: What do you mean, "equally spaced vectors?"

Comment: What it means, is that for each of the $N$ vectors, the angles that this vector makes with its closest neighbors are equal, and this value of angle is the same for all the $N$ vectors.

Comment: For that, the phrase you're essentially looking for is "roots of unity."

Comment: I know roots of unity in $2D$ but I am unaware of roots of unity in $3D$.

Comment: @Hosam: as stated you can use the same solution as in $\mathbb{R}^2$, just write down the vertices of a regular $n$-gon in some plane, say the $xy$-plane. Presumably this is not what you have in mind but you need to adjust the definition to exclude this case.

Comment: Sounds like you may be talking about the Thomson Problem: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomson_problem